# how to enable and disable list box when user type text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my html code as follows,

```
<body>
<ul>
<div id="branch" class="leaf">
<label class="control select" title>
    <span class="wrap">Select Branch</span>
    <select>
        <option value"~Nothing~" selected="selected">---</option>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
        <option value="A1">A1</option>
        <option value="A2">A2</option>
    </select>
    <span class="warning"</span>
</label>
</div>
<div id="Product" class="leaf">
<label class="control select" title>
    <span class="wrap">Select Product</span>
    <select>
        <option value"~Nothing~" selected="selected">---</option>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
        <option value="Loan">Loan</option>
        <option value="Interest">Interest</option>
    </select>
    <span class="warning"</span>
</label>
</div>
<div id="Account" class="leaf">
<label class="control input text" title>
    <span class="wrap">Select Account</span>
    <input class type="text" value="[Null]">
    <span class="warning"></span>
</label>
</div>
</ul>
</body>
```

Now when user enters account number in account field it automatically disable product and branch list boxes. To perform those validations i have used jQuery script and it is as follows:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {        

/*Enable disable Branch, Product when Account number is entered*/

jQuery(document).on('blur', '#Account label.control input', function (event) {

    var txtstatus=document.querySelector('#Account label.control input ').value;

        if(txtstatus=="Inactive"){
            jQuery("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
            jQuery("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
            return false;
        }

        if(txtstatus=="Active"){
            jQuery("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
            jQuery("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
        } 
    });


jQuery("#apply").click(function(){
var txtstatus=document.querySelector('#Account label.control input ').value;

/*Validations for account number*/
if(txtstatus.match(/^[0-9]{12}$/)==null){           
    alert("Enter valid Account Number");
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
    }

    /*if(txtstatus=="Inactive"){
        jQuery("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        jQuery("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        return false;
    }
    if(txtstatus=="Active"){
        jQuery("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
        jQuery("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
    } */

});    
});


</script>
```

After execution it is not enabling or disabling list box but validation to account number is working fine. Please suggest me how to perform enabling / disabling list box.

Comment: On want conditions you  want to enable list boxes ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. When user enters account number in the text box automatically the two list boxes should get disabled else enable. Like when user enters branch, product and account number is the flow then everything should be enable. If user enters directly account number then product and branch should get disable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Xv4vH/). check and alter accordingly,, it does disable select when you enter Inactive

```
   if(txtstatus=="Inactive"){
        jQuery("#branch").find('label.control select').prop('disabled','disabled');
        jQuery("#Product").find('label.control select').prop('disabled','disabled');
        return false;
    }
    if(txtstatus=="Active"){
        jQuery("#branch").find('label.control select').prop('disabled',false);
        jQuery("#Product").find('label.control select').prop('disabled',false);
    }
```

Comment: here is updated link , check and let me know http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Xv4vH/1/  .. if u will enter account number directly , both select wil get disabled.. you will have to re run from start.. i dont know in application what is your condition to enable select again

Comment: When i execute piece of code which you have shared with me it is giving "Uncaught ReferenceError: branchvalue is not defined " i think i cannot use that if condition "if(branchValue == "---" && productValue == "---"){"

Comment: have you compared it with working code in fiddle..  i have defined.....     var branchValue =  jQuery("#branch").find('label.control select').val();

Comment: yes. After implementing your fiddle code it is showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is modification in your script. Hope so you are expecting similar output.

```
<script>

$(function(){


/*Enable disable Branch, Product when Account number is entered*/

//$(document).live('keypress', '#Account label.control input', function (event) {
$('#Account label.control input').keypress(function(event){

    var txtstatus=$('#Account label.control input').val();//document.querySelector('#Account label.control input ').value;

        if(txtstatus != ""){
            $("#branch").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#Product").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',true);   
            //$("").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
            //return false;
        }else if(txtstatus=="Active"){
             $("#branch").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',false);
            $("#Product").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',false); 
        }else{
           $("#branch").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',false);
            $("#Product").find('label.control').children("select").attr('disabled',false);
}
console.log("you press key.."); 
    });


$("#apply").click(function(){
var txtstatus=document.querySelector('#Account label.control input ').value;

/*Validations for account number*/
if(txtstatus.match(/^[0-9]{12}$/)==null){           
    alert("Enter valid Account Number");
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
    }

    /*if(txtstatus=="Inactive"){
        $("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        $("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        return false;
    }
    if(txtstatus=="Active"){
        $("#branch").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
        $("#Product").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
    } */

});    



});
</script>
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Aniket, it is still displaying list of values when i enter account number

Comment: When should be the select box displayed as disabled?? I mean when you are enterin the text or after you have entered ??

Comment: while entering text itself it should get disabled and should be like that only after also

Comment: But on what condition it should be disabled ?? when he enters Inactive that time  ??

Comment: yes when user enters value in account number text box it should get disabled

Comment: and when should it be enabled ??

Comment: I have modified the code just check if its working now as you are expecting.

Comment: By default it should be product and branch should be in enable state. only when user enters account number then product and branch should go into disable state.

Comment: Can you give me your skype ID or else gmailID. so that i can clearly ask you what exactly you want.